# Read URL content XCode sigabrt error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt

Here is my code and it gives `"Program received signal "SIGABRT".`
I'm new at `iOS` Development.

```
- (IBAction)getData {

    NSURL *URL = @"http://www.oeslabs.com/aa.txt";

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];    
    if (string == nil) {

        // an error occurred
        label1.text =@"Error";
    }
    else{
        label1.text = string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Also Can put code as

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.oeslabs.com/aa.txt"];
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
.
.
.
.
.
```

Here is Official Documentation of [stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) use for convert the legal `URL` string.

Comment: @albatross-i am glad to help you, keep it up :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign `NSString`
 to `NSURL`

replace

```
NSURL *URL = @"http://www.oeslabs.com/aa.txt";
```

With

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.oeslabs.com/aa.txt"];
```